# Problem shutting down or restarting after suspend.16.04

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, 16.04, acpi

Yesterday I noticed when I went to restart my laptop, it wouldn't. The computer is a brand new Dell XPS 13 9350. After looking into some things I noticed that it would only happen (Not shutting down) after I made my computer go into suspend mode, either by shutting the lid or manually suspending it. I did a `dmesg` and found there were some ACPI errors at startup and after suspend or wakeup was triggered.

Here is a message at startup, which seems to repeat a few times.

```
[    0.963116] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECAV] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[    0.963121] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FNCL] (Node ffff88027611c4d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[    0.963126] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FN00._ON] (Node ffff8802760ebed8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[    0.963132] acpi PNP0C0B:00: Failed to change power state to D0
[    0.971338] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECAV] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[    0.971344] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FNCL] (Node ffff88027611c4d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[    0.971353] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FN00._ON] (Node ffff8802760ebed8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[    0.971371] acpi PNP0C0B:00: Setting initial power state
[    0.983179] acpi PNP0C0B:00: Cannot transition from (unknown) to D3hot
```

Here is the message during the suspend or wakeup procedures.

```
[   61.650365] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[   62.980908] acpi LNXPOWER:1b: Turning OFF
[   62.988316] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECAV] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[   62.988319] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FNCL] (Node ffff88027611c4d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[   62.988322] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FN04._OFF] (Node ffff88027611c410), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[   62.988334] acpi LNXPOWER:1a: Turning OFF
[   62.996318] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECAV] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[   62.996320] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FNCL] (Node ffff88027611c4d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[   62.996322] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FN03._OFF] (Node ffff88027611c2d0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[   62.996333] acpi LNXPOWER:19: Turning OFF
[   63.004325] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECAV] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[   63.004327] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FNCL] (Node ffff88027611c4d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[   63.004329] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FN02._OFF] (Node ffff88027611c190), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[   63.004340] acpi LNXPOWER:18: Turning OFF
[   63.012333] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECAV] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[   63.012335] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FNCL] (Node ffff88027611c4d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[   63.012337] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FN01._OFF] (Node ffff88027611c050), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[   63.012348] acpi LNXPOWER:17: Turning OFF
[   63.020337] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECAV] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[   63.020339] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FNCL] (Node ffff88027611c4d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[   63.020341] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FN00._OFF] (Node ffff8802760ebf00), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[   63.036963] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[   63.037059] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 16.295 msecs
[   63.045997] PM: early resume of devices complete after 8.905 msecs
[   63.051186] rtc_cmos 00:01: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[   63.086972] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 3 resume PLC timeout
[   63.105472] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 2 resume PLC timeout
[   63.123459] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 0 resume PLC timeout
[   63.405106] usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   63.757318] usb 1-4: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   63.942128] usb 1-4: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[   64.109488] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   64.231076] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[   64.462123] usb 1-1: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   64.715595] PM: resume of devices complete after 1668.139 msecs
[   64.716040] PM: Finishing wakeup.
```

Some of the things I have found has pointed me to updating my BIOS, but my BIOS is already updated to the latest version, which I updated last week. Any help would be very much appreciated. I can provide more information if needed.